# Is there an Android equivalent of Java's glass pane?

Tags: android

I would like to be able to make temporary drawings on top of my view hierarchy without invoking onDraw() events of the hierarchy.  The glass pane works well for this purpose.  Is there an Android equivalent?

Comment: Did I answer this question to your satisfaction? If not, let me know how I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no equivalent by default; you will need to write your own GlassPane class. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362213/problems-with-scrolling-in-linearlayout) for an example (I haven't tested it, but it looks pretty legit).